# Google App Engine Instance Hours for every 10min job

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an script in App engine that gets called every 10min.  I am the only user.
The script pulls data from a web source does light processing and returns an image.  It takes several minutes to run the first time.  The source gets updated every 10min, so the next time my script runs, (10min later), it returns in a few seconds.

I'm using over 30 instance hours a day which is over the 28 free hours.

I read somewhere that every time an instance starts, it uses a minimum of 15min.  (so 144x15=36hrs)
Therefore, am I better off trying to keep the instance running 24hrs (using up 24hrs) and limiting to one instance max?  Perhaps setting idle_timeout to 10min.  Another potential way to save would be to somehow pause my script during late night/early morning hours.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing) is where you likely found the 15 minutes minimum statement and it refers to when the accrual of instance hours ends. If you look at that documentation you will see that it depends on what type of scaling you are using.

Here are my tought in all options you mentioned on your question for staying in the free tier:

- Use only one instance. The problem with this approach is that giving a higher load to a single instance may increase other cost such as vCPU and memory since all the processing will be done there, also, it's likely that it's going to take longer to run the script.
- Pause the script on low activity hours, this will be the ideal if the acumulated load when turning it back on it not too big.
- Setting `idle_timeout` to 10min. This won't work if it runs every 10 min on all instances, since your app runs every 10min and app engine will only stop charging you every 15min idle, which will never happen, unless it does not run every 10min for every instance, if that is the case, it could be worth trying.

So, summing it up, all 3 options have their pros and cons, I would suggest that you test all of them and see what options suits your needs better.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks.  I've discovered that idle_timeout is not an option because it does not work with automatic scaling which forces me to use a backend instance which gives me far less free hours.  Using a frontend instance (F2), I tried setting min/max_instances and min/max_idle_instances to 1.  I'm still testing this.  I'll look into a way to reject requests over a certain time period.  This isnt ideal but may be my only choice

Comment: Great, let me know what comes out of the tests, I would also recommend that you post an answer with your final solution once you find it, so that the community can refer to it if they came across the same issue, also, if you found my solution helpful in any way, consider upvoting it.

Comment: So I implemented something to only do the every 10min update when my laptop is not idle.  That cut it down to about 70 requests, averaging 3sec response time, racking up about 21 front-end instance hrs.  Still alot higher than I'd like.  My concern is that it seems that each request is costing me at least 15min time even if the requests are less than 15min apart.

Comment: This is expected, since the 15min is the minimum time before you stop being charged after being idle.

Comment: Is there any way around this?  Is there a way to keep the instance up longer (ie 15min) so it can handle other requests?  Right now about 3-4hrs of actual use is using up over 20hrs

Comment: Unfortunately this is how App Engine is built so if you keep your script running every 10 minutes you will never stop being billed by idle time, what you could do is run the script every 20 min, that way you would get 15min idle per hour, which would represent 6 less billed hours per instance per day.